# Flask-sqlalchemy invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'

Tags: python, flask, valueerror

So I've created a db.model and I've created a login system using Flask-Login everything seemed to work and now all of a sudden it gives the "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None' ". Apparently something that actually contains nothing is being passed but I can't see what and where. Can anyone help?
Here's my highlighted code pieces which are said to be causing my problems:

```
return Users.query.get(int(user_id))
```

and

```
return render_template('Index.html', New_User=All_Users)
```

those two are parts of the following code pieces:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
     return Users.query.get(int(user_id))


def Index():
if request.method=='POST':
    New_Username = request.form['Username']
    New_Password = request.form['Password']
    user = Users.query.filter_by(Username=New_Username).first()
    if not user:
        New_User = Users(Username=New_Username, Password=New_Password)
        db.session.add(New_User)
        db.session.commit()
        login_user(New_User)
        return redirect('/Dashboard')
    else:
        return render_template('Index.html', New_User=All_Users)
else:
        return render_template('Index.html', New_User=All_Users)
```

Whole traceback:

```
File "E:\Python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

File "E:\Python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "E:\Python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "E:\Python\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "E:\Python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "E:\Python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "E:\Python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "E:\Python\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "E:\Python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "E:\Python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "run.py", line 56, in Index
return render_template('Index.html', New_User=All_Users)
File "E:\Python\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 136, in render_template
ctx.app.update_template_context(context)
File "E:\Python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 838, in update_template_context
context.update(func())
File "E:\Python\Lib\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 379, in _user_context_processor
return dict(current_user=_get_user())
File "E:\Python\Lib\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 346, in _get_user
current_app.login_manager._load_user()
File "E:\Python\Lib\site-packages\flask_login\login_manager.py", line 318, in _load_user
user = self._user_callback(user_id)
File "run.py", line 30, in load_user
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.Username}'
 
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return Users.query.get(int(user_id))
 
 
 
@app.route('/Logout')
@login_required
```

Comment: please add whole `traceback`

Comment: who is passing  the user_id to `load_user`?

Comment: Added the whole  traceback

Comment: maybe ```user_id``` is ```None```? also try removing the ```in()``` cast

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you query the `Users` model on a login, your `user_loader` returns the user to your '/login' view function, or whatever calls `login_user()`. When you query the database, if there's a 404 (so the user is not found), `None` is returned. You have tried to handle this with `if not user:...`, but you should instead try `if user is None`, or `if user==None` or even take the error as default and say `if user is not None: #code for logging in`. Then your view function will handle the database returning `None` from the query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !!